# Multiple variable className in next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, classname

How to apply multiple className in Next js, in which there are variable classsnames as well ? 
I'm using [component level css](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) approach

#### Here's my code and what I want to do:

```js
import styles from "./ColorGroup.module.css";

const colors = ["red", "sky", "yellow", "green", "golden"];

const ColorGroup = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.colorContainer}>
      <text>Colour</text>
      <div className={styles.colorBoxContainer}>
        {colors.map((color, index) => (
          <div
            // variable color class is not get applied, only colorBox is applied, I want both
            className={`${styles}.${color} ${styles.colorBox}`}
            key={index}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Goal:

[image]

#### CSS code:

```css
/* code for layout and arrangement above */

.colorBox {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}

.red {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.sky {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.golden {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

But this method is only applying the colorBox className and not doing anything for `${styles}.${color}` . **How to apply both ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bracket

```
<div className={styles.colorBoxContainer}>
    {colors.map((color, index) => (
        <div
            className={`${styles[color]} ${styles.colorBox}`}
            key={index}
        ></div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the style object, it easier to use it with variables :

```
<div key={index} className={`${styles.colorBox}`} style={{ backgroundColor: color }} >
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach didn't come to my mind :D But do you know how to apply those classNames, if we want to do something more than just backgroundColor ?